# How to feed the model with a set of images at once instead of one by one image?

Tags: python, image

I have a dataset of CT lung images, each patient has a series of CT images like the follows:

[image]

I want to feed the model with a stack of images for each patient, so I have converted to .nii.gz:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import glob

file_names = sorted(glob.glob('/path/to/dataset/patient/*.png'))
reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
reader.SetFileNames(file_names)
vol = reader.Execute()
sitk.WriteImage(vol, '/path/to/dataset/patient/2639.nii.gz')
```

I have build my model to receive image as one numpy array not a stack of nii images, How can I feed the model with a stack of images in nii.gz.

I'm trying to resize nii.gz to 2D image :

```
import skimage.transform as skTrans
img = nib.load('/1164.nii.gz').get_fdata()
img = skTrans.resize(img, (128,128), order=1, preserve_range=True)
img.shape
```

but that raises this warning:

> warnings.warn(msg)  UserWarning: Anti-aliasing will be enabled by
> default in skimage 0.15 to avoid aliasing artifacts when down-sampling
> images.   warn("Anti-aliasing will be enabled by default in skimage
> 0.15 to "

And the shape is changed but the number of images not:
(128, 128, 113)
113 is the number of images.

Comment: With any luck, loading the stack with SimpleITK already gives you a single 3D numpy array. What have you tried?

Comment: So what is the problem here? You have a 3D image of size 128x128x113 – do you want 128x128x128?

Comment: I want to be one image 128*128

Comment: So one slice out of those 113? I'm really not following what the resultant 2D image should be if you already have a 3D image...

Comment: because my model is a 2D model can't receive a 3D image

Comment: So then just use Numpy indexing to pick one slice out of the 118?

Comment: No I want all 113 images to be one image

Comment: How would you lay out those 118 images in one 2D image?

Comment: @AKX I don't know

Comment: Then it's impossible to help.